# How can I calculate $\left [ \vec{x} \right ]_b$ from $\left [ \vec{x} \right ]_E$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I did almost whole example. But i dont get this part.

How can I calculate $\left [ \vec{x} \right ]_b$ from $\left [ \vec{x} \right ]_E$. Take care that $\left [ \vec{x} \right ]_E=\vec{x}$?

Example and my previous calculation:

In $\mathbb{R}^3$ the canonical basis $E=\left (\mathbf{e_1},\mathbf{e_2},\mathbf{e_3}  \right )$ and $B=\left (\mathbf{b_1},\mathbf{b_2},\mathbf{b_3}  \right )$ with
$\mathbf{b_1}=(1,2,4)^T$, $\mathbf{b_2}=(0,-1,1)^T$ and $\mathbf{b_3}=(2,3,8)^T$.

How do I determine for vector $\mathbf{v}=2\mathbf{e_1}+\mathbf{e_2}+2\mathbf{e_3}$ coordinates $\left \lfloor \mathbf{v} \right \rfloor_E$ and $\left \lfloor \mathbf{v} \right \rfloor_b$ ?

a) $\left \lfloor \mathbf{v} \right \rfloor_E$ =$\begin{pmatrix} 2\\ 1\\ 
2\end{pmatrix}$
$\left \lfloor \mathbf{v} \right \rfloor_b$ =$\begin{pmatrix} -16\\ 6\\  
9\end{pmatrix}$

How do I determine for vector $\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{b_1}+2\mathbf{b_2}+3\mathbf{b_3}$ coordinates $\left \lfloor \mathbf{w} \right \rfloor_E$ and $\left \lfloor \mathbf{w} \right \rfloor_b$ ?

b)
 $\left \lfloor \mathbf{w} \right \rfloor_E$ =$\begin{pmatrix} 7\\ 9\\ 
30\end{pmatrix}$
$\left \lfloor \mathbf{v} \right \rfloor_b$ =$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2\\  
3\end{pmatrix}$

c)Determine the transformation matrix T of the coordinate transformation from the base E to the base B, where the old coordinates on E and the new coordinates refer to B. Note: Determine the matrix T such that applies

$\left [ \vec{x} \right ]_E=T\left [ \vec{x} \right ]_B $

$T=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2\\ 
 2& -1 &3 \\ 
 4&  1& 8
\end{pmatrix}$

d) How can I calculate $\left [ \vec{x} \right ]_b$ from $\left [ \vec{x} \right ]_E$. (If we know that $\left [ \vec{x} \right ]_E=\vec{x}$)

I would be very thankful if someone could help me with d).

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by the inverse of the matrix $T$.
$$ [x]_E = T[x]_B \implies [x]_B = T^{-1}[x]_E $$

Comment: XE is (100, 010, 001) right?

Comment: I was trying to follow your notation. $[x]_E$ is meant to be the vector $x$ written in terms of the $e$ basis.